# CoreData one-to-many relationship. Problem with NSSet attribution

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

Good afternoon. It's not the first day I've been thinking about this task. I have a one-to-many CoreData table.

[image]
[image]

I was able to link Property to Folders. That is, folders contain many properties. A piece of code at the bottom, how to link the tables

```
var selectedFolder: Folders?
do {
            arrayPropertys = try context.fetch(Property.fetchRequest())
            arrayPropertys[indexPath.row].parentFolders = selectedFolder
}
```

On the main screen, I need to show the properties that are in a specific folder that is pressed. The amount I can take:

```
arrayPropertys[indexPath.row].parentFolders?.propertys!.count
```

Shows the quantity correctly. For example, there are 5 properties in one folder, and 2 properties in another.

The question is that I can't pull the attributes. There is a Name attribute, but because of the type of the NSSet object, it does not want to be shown.

[image]
[image]

I can't get the values out in any way, I've tried everything, I've read on the Internet. It doesn't work. I can see it and I can't reach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `(parentFolders?.propertys?.allObjects as? [Property])` to access the objects as an `Array<Property>`

Comment: Actually it is `parentFolders?.propertys?.allObjects` I misread your code.

Comment: let pr = (arrayPropertys[indexPath.row].parentFolders?.propertys!.allObjects)! as Array and this doesn't work as array. This is array, but they have no "name"

Comment: All you have to do is cast it from there

Comment: arrayPropertys[indexPath.row].parentFolders?.propertys?.allObjects as? [Property] Sorry, this?

Comment: Something like that. I don't have the full picture of your model but yeah

Comment: let pr = (arrayPropertys[indexPath.row].parentFolders?.propertys?.allObjects as [Property]) as Array<Property> ad this doesn't work(

Comment: It is already an array you don't need `as Array<Property>` that is just a description

Comment: oh, no...there is such a situation here... xcode did not highlight to me that there are attributes(( I tried to put them now and everything turned out!